Proving that a line segment and unions of are closed in in standard topology
Here is the second exercise I would ask confirmation/feedbacks for. I'm asked to say which among $A, \overline{A}, A_k$ are closed / compacts (standard topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$), where $\overline{A}$ denotes the closure of $A$.
$$A_k = \{(x, y) \in [0, 1] \times [0, 1]: kx+ ky = 1\}$$
and $k$ is a natural number greater than $0$.
$$A = \bigcup_{k \geq 1} A_k$$
So this is what I did.
I wrote $kx + ky = 1$ as $y = \frac{1}{k} - x$ hence the family of all the translated bisector lines in the first quadrant. Being $x, y$ bounded between $0$ and $1$, the geometric meaning of each $A_k$ is a triangle, hence closed and bounded per se.
Here again as $n\to +\infty$ I arrive at the "line" $y = -x$ hence the point $(0, 0)$ which is not an element of $A_k$ hence the set is not closed.
The closure I expect now to be $\overline{A} = A \cup \{(0, 0)\}$ or better $A \cup \{(x, y)\in [0, 1]\times [0, 1]: y = -x\}$.
This is now closed.
Well, as always I need confirmations or critics.. Thank you very much!

Your definitions needs clarification: For example, $A = {(x, y) \in [0, 1] \times [0, 1]: kx+ ky = 1}$ is wrong. Since the condition involves $k$ it should be $A_k$ instead of $A$. But then what is the set $A$?

@jjagmath Thank you so much, sorry for my errors. I edited the question!

I added the tag solution-verification with description "For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so. This should not be the only tag for a question, and should not be used to circumvent site policies regarding duplicate questions. " Your question does not satisfy this requirement. I suggest you make clear which part of your solution is in doubt.

$A_k$ is not a triangle, it's a line segment.

I think that your exercise question is, of the sets $A$, $\overline{A}$, and $A_k$ (for each $k$), which are closed? And that your answer is that $A$ is not closed, $\overline{A}$ is closed, and $A_k$ is closed for each $k$. This is correct (and in fact the closure of any set is trivially closed). And your description of $\overline{A}$ is exactly right.
However, your proof that $A_k$ is closed is not clear. As @jjagmath points out, it is a line segment. To show that it is closed, basically you use the fact that addition and multiplication are continuous. For example, if you have a sequence of points $(x_i, y_i)$ in $A_k$ and $(x_i, y_i) \to (x, y)$, then $kx + ky = k(\lim x_i) + k(\lim y_i) = \lim kx_i + \lim ky_i = \lim (kx_i + ky_i) = \lim 1 = 1$, so $(x, y)$ is also in $A_k$.

Please strive not to answer off-topic solution verification questions (doing so violates site policy).
